# Atualizar o select após cadastro sem refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Boa tarde, este é meu primeiro post, gostaria da ajuda de vcs, tenho um select option que busca os dados no bd, logo após este tenho um botão onde abro uma janela modal para incluir mais opções a este select caso necessite, com isso faço um cadstro no bd sem dar refresh na página, isto pq já tenho itens inseridos nos demais inputs, o que eu preciso é que após o cadastro este select option seja atualizado sem o refres da página.
segue o código.

```
<select id="location" name="reup"  >
<option value="">item</option>
<?php aqui vem os demais option com a busca no bd   ?>
</select>
```

jquery:

```
$('#insert').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var nomer = $('#nomer').val();
    .....
    var obsr = $('#obsr').val();

    $.post('insreu.php', {
        nomer:nomer,
        .....
        obsr:obsr
    }, function(resposta){

        if(resposta == 1){

            $('input, textarea').val('');
            $('#reup').append(e);
            alert('Cadastrado com sucesso.');
        }else {
            alert(resposta);
        }
    });

});
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo para isso dividir seu código em dois arquivo, um primeiro que irá conter todas as informações da página e um segundo que será um auxiliador do jquery para realizar uma nova consulta, que irá conter apenas as options.

#### default.php

```
<select id="location" name="reup">

    <!-- Arquivo que será incluído o arquivo que será responsável por mostrar as options atualizadas -->
    <?php include "options.php"; ?>

</select>
```

---

#### options.php

No arquivo `options.php`, deverá conter a consulta no servidor e trazer as options para ser mostrada no campo de seleção.

```
<option value="">item</option>
<?php aqui vem os demais option com a busca no bd   ?>
```

---

#### JavaScript

No JS, iremos continuar fazendo a inclusão normal como já está sendo feita, mas iremos adicionar um `.load()` para recarregar o arquivo `options.php` após a inserção da nova opção, com isso irá trazer o campo de seleção com as opções atualizadas.

```
$('#insert').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var nomer = $('#nomer').val();
    .....
    var obsr = $('#obsr').val();

    $.post('insreu.php', {
        nomer:nomer,
        .....
        obsr:obsr
    }, function(resposta){

        if(resposta == 1){

            $('input, textarea').val('');
            $('#reup').append(e);


            // Aqui iremos recarregar o elemento com o name=reup, o recarregamento será apenas nesse elemento e irá recarregar o arquivo options.php, com isso irá realizar a consulta novamente das opções disponíveis
            $('[name="reup"]').load('options.php');


            alert('Cadastrado com sucesso.');

        }else {
            alert(resposta);
        }
    });

});
```

---

#### Referência: [load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: boa tarde, ainda continuo com o problema, faço o cadastro sem o refresh na página, mas não consigo fazer o refresh no select

Comment: Apareceu algum erro no console? Você não conseguiu é muito amplo

Comment: Acabei de acertar, coloquei um id na div do select que fica fora da janela modal, no final mandei atualizar a div assim q fizesse o insert, meu problema agora é outro, tenho 5 selects  fazendo com que eu tenha 5 janelas modais neste formulário, logo o primeiro funciona sem problemas , mas não consigo inserir no bd os demais, as modais funcionam mas o inserts não, estou seguindo a mesma lógica, e claro cada modal com sua identificação distinta.

Comment: ficou assim : obsr:obsr
        }).done(function(href){ 
  $("#atualizareu").load( href +" #atualizareu");
  });
  $('#modalreu').modal('hide');
  });

ja acertei os demais, falta de atenção, havia esquecido dos id's nos inputs

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar `$.ajax()` no lugar do `$.post()`, para usar `JSON` como retorno dos dados, assim ao salvar você já retornaria todos os dados para dentro do select, inclusive o dado que inseriu.

Neste caso você retornaria um JSON com os valores e trataria a resposta gerando seus `options` e depois inserindo em seu select, já selecionando a opção que criou.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "insreu.php",
    data: {
        nomer: nomer,
        obsr: obsr
    },
    dataType: "JSON",
    beforeSend: function () {
        $('#location').html('<option value="">Carregando...</option>')
    },
    success: function (response) {
        if (response) {
            var select = "";
            $.each(response, function (index, value) { 
                select += '<option value="+index+">+value+</option>';
            });
            $('#location').html(select);
            $('#location').val(seuvalorenviado)
        }
    }
});
```